# Can we get double upgrade in plants vs zombies 2?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

One from in game coins and one for real purchase?

For example, if plant slots are bought and then we unlock the key, do we have 2 extra plant slots?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you always ask your questions in the first person plural? It's an... unusual stylistic choice, given the content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ones you purchase are separate from the ones you earn in the game.  Its possible to have 2 max slots, 50 more sun at the start, 5 plant food, etc, if you purchase the upgrade as well as unlock the in game version.